# could not login to X-SERVER

Tags: kde, xfce

i have 3 user account in system with `kde` and `xfce` . in `x-server` i can not login with all created users.

in terminal after restart x-server and `kdm` or `xfce` i do not get any error. login interminal not problem but i can not login with `kde` or `xfce`.
`or`xfce`.

Comment: you need to clarify it a bit more why you can't login exactly, what's happening when you try to login?

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish after remove .kde and create new user i can not login

Comment: this is not telling me anything. Why can't you login? it logins to a black screen or it's just stuck in a loop? Did you create account password protected and everytime you enter the password it doesn't react on anything? please add more detailed information.

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish after enter username and password thats looping and get username password again. restart x-server

Comment: that's what you should've mentioned from the beginning. Read this http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634

Comment: @JohnnyEnglish this link do not resolve my problem :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15023/discussion-between-tuxworld-and-johnnyenglish).

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions:

Login to `tty` (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and remove the `.Xauthority` file and also need to remove the `.xsession-errors` files.

```
sudo rm .Xauthority
sudo rm .xsession-errors*
```

or also back it up:

```
sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Check the home directory:

```
ls -l /home
```

you may have to give ownership back to your account using `chown`

```
sudo chown -R username:group /home/username
```

More answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop/223634#223634)

Comment: i'm going all of this ways. not resolve my problem. .xsession-errors result: `Xsession: X session started for tux-world at Wed Jun 11 10:16:59 IRDT 2014
open: Permission denied` and `-rw-------  1 tux-world tux-world    0 Jun 11 10:18 .Xauthority`

Comment: did you do what's written in my answer? do you have root (sudo) privileges? you cannot do this as a simple user.

Comment: moving `.Xauthority` and `chown -R tux-world:tux-world ` for /home/tux-world and for finish running `servise lightdm restart`.

Comment: remove it with commands in my answer, this tutorial works for sure otherwise you experience problems with something else.

Comment: why thats looping for get username password. i see `open: Permission denied` in `.xsession-errors` file.

Comment: `permission denied` because you're doing it without or you don't have root priviliges, can you login as `sudo su` and repeat it?

Comment: .xsession-errors content: `Xsession: X session started for tux-world at Wed Jun 11 10:51:28 IRDT 2014

localuser:tux-world being added to access control list

OpenSSL version mismatch. Built against 1000105f, you have 10001080` and looping againg for get username password

Comment: read [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=732940) what is your **distro** by default?